# Errors using own new library - Can't resolve file path?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have created a new React component library (we'll call `LIB`) for myself that I am now wanting to use within another project, including it as a dependency as you would normally expect.

`LIB` has `"type": "module"` in its `package.json` and builds a `/dist` directory.

**`LIB` file structure example**

```
.
└── LIB/
    └── src/
        └── container/
            ├── index.ts
            ├── container.tsx
            ├── container-footer.tsx
            └── ...
```

**container/index.ts**

```
export * from './container';
export * from './container-footer';
export ...
```

The `ContainerFooter` component itself will never be called on its own outside of this library and is only there to split out code from the main `Container` component where it is of course imported - Perhaps I should not be including it in the `index.ts` exports?

**container/container.tsx**

```
import { ContainerFooter } from './container-footer';

const Container = props => (
    <div>
        {/* Some stuff here */}

        {props.showFooter && <ContainerFooter />}
    </div>
)
```

However, I am facing issues when attempting to use `LIB` within my other project:

1. I cannot seem to import the component at the high level: `import { Container } from '@company_name/LIB'`, instead I get the error:

```
ERROR in ./src/App.tsx
export ‘Container’ (imported as ‘Container’) was not found in ‘@company_name/LIB’ (module has no exports)
```

2. When importing the component from the bundled `dist` directory: `import { Container } from '@company_name/LIB/dist/container/container'` - *Note, I also could not get it to import from `/dist/container` with it giving the same error as above.*

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/@company_name/LIB/dist/container/container.js 6:0-47
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './container-footer' in '/Users/username/git/NEW_PROJECT/node_modules/@company_name/LIB/dist/container'
Did you mean 'container-footer.js'?
BREAKING CHANGE: The request './container-footer' failed to resolve only because it was resolved as fully specified
(probably because the origin is strict EcmaScript Module, e. g. a module with javascript mimetype, a '*.mjs' file, or a '*.js' file where the package.json contains '"type": "module"').
The extension in the request is mandatory for it to be fully specified.
Add the extension to the request.
```

This error looks like it's suggesting I change the import within `LIB/src/container/container` of the `ContainerFooter` to contain the filename or something like I have never seen before...

I'm not entirely sure what is going wrong here. The only thing I can see that is slightly different from the standard libraries I've seen is that I have split out the code into separate files and imported them back into the main component...

Should I have not included these split-out components in the exports within the `index.ts`? Is that causing the issue?

As far as I know I am not using any third party bundler like rollup or webpack to build this, but just relying on typescript with the `tsc` command.

**LIB/package.json (non-dependency bits)**

```
{
    "files": [
        "dist"
    ],
    "main": "dist/index.js",
    "type": "module",
    "types": "dist/index.d.ts",
    "scripts": {
        "build": "tsc",
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

**LIB/tsconfig.json**

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "allowJs": true,
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "baseUrl": "src",
        "declaration": true,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "isolatedModules": true,
        "jsx": "react-jsx",
        "lib": [
            "dom",
            "dom.iterable",
            "esnext"
        ],
        "module": "esnext",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "outDir": "dist",
        "resolveJsonModule": true,
        "rootDirs": [
            "src"
        ],
        "skipLibCheck": true,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "strict": true,
        "strictNullChecks": false,
        "target": "esnext"
    },
    "include": [
        "src/**/*"
    ]
}
```

Comment: I think you should read through [the Node module documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/packages.html#modules-packages), in particular the sections about what can be done with "exports" clauses in the `package.json` file.